# Appmaker Cloud SQL PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

As of now Appmaker doesnt support PostgreSQL on Cloud SQL. Will it be supported in the future. Is it on the roadmap.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Stackoverflow is the best place to ask such questions, with the same success you can ask what color will be next Pixel phone. I can speculate that it will be logical move from Google since PostgreSQL is already supported by Cloud Platform, but I doubt that anybody on the planet Earth can give you an exact date.

You may ask your G Suite admin to reach out Google Support, maybe you'll have more luck going that way.